# Example of Serialization in Unity; with different instances of the same class

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

I am having troubles finding an example about serialization, with more than one object.

In general the examples show the serialization through one object (usually a class created with the purpose to hold data that you want to save or load). That is fine, but I can't find something that show how to do serialization and de-serialization with further objects.

I am envisioning a case where I have different instances of a class type, so I am not sure how do I de-serialize in this case.

This is how I serialize:

```
BinaryFormatter savegame_formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

FileStream savefile = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath +
                                "/savegame.dat", FileMode.Open);
savegame_formatter.Serialize(savefile, Player1Data);
savegame_formatter.Serialize(savefile, Player2Data);
savefile.Close();
```

Both serialized class are the same class (PlayerData); just 2 different instances; with different values. When de-serializing, how do you distinguish between the 2 instances?

```
BinaryFormatter loadgame_formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream loadfile = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savegame.dat", FileMode.Open);
// How do you deserialize Player1Data and Player2Data?
PlayerData cloned = (PlayerData)loadgame_formatter.Deserialize(loadfile);
```

Comment: What not use json that will write everything to a file and deserialize them back?

Comment: Would that be simpler? Most of the example show the binary approach, although I never had to deal with this scenario, so I am not sure why one would be preferred to the other.

Comment: Yes that would be simpler and that's the way you are suppose to do it. There were many examples of `BinaryFormatter` because Json wasn't naively supported. Now, it is. If you need an example, let me know. Just update your question with what `PlayerData` class looks like.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you are overwriting the save file. You want to open in in Append mode. Putting your save data instances in a list or array is a good idea too. Then you can `foreach` them, write to file, add some sort of delimiter after each successful serialization and then use the same steps but in reverse for deserializing(read the file up to first delimiter, desirialize that, repeat). Alternatively you can create separate save files for each save data instance. In this case use the same iterating over arrays tactic.

Comment: Right; I didn't realize that I am overwriting every time. Beside that, I assume that there is no straightforward way to deserialize multiple objects that are instaces of the same one I guess. Multiple save files would increase risk to break things, which is why I am trying to use only one file.

Comment: @newbiez the straight forward way is to add some separator in your single file. Then read the text up to that separator. Pass that text to the desirialization, desirialize, put the new object in a array(or implement some kind of factory), rince repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Uri, I did think about how I can work around this, and figured out that a dictionary could be serialized, and that would allow me to save data neatly and solve the issue.

Instead of making multiple calls with multiple object to serialize; I can simply create a custom dictionary, with `<string, object>` as definition, and store the whole dictionary as serialized in the external file.

I will try this now, and see if it works.